# Problem opening PDF files from internal/portable storage through a internal webpage

Tags: android, pdf

OK. This is a weird one: we've got a mess of Web sites that our nonprofit wants to distribute on Android devices to places that lack Internet (been doing it for 20 years with Windows...)

Many of these sites have PDF files... which will not, under certain circumstances, open on an Android tablet (Lenovo) or phone (Motorola) running Android 7.1.1

Here's the rub: if we open the file directly from a file browser, it works and gets served up as...

http://127.0.0.1:27101/sdcard/0/storage/E823-8032/PNGChip/sample.pdf

But we get an "Unable to download file" message if we use the mount point...

file:///sdcard/PNGChip/sample.pdf

To confirm: all the other file types open fine using either protocol.

We're mostly working with FireFox, but we've tested other browsers and gotten the same results, which has me thinking it's an Android "feature."

Anybody see this before? Is there a cure?

Comment: `if we open the file directly from a file browser, it works and gets served up as...

http://127.0.0.1:27101....` What is happening here? A file browser that implements a webserver to serve a file? Never seen one like that. Please explain. Also explain which app(s) is/are used to display pdfs.

Comment: Please show the code that uses both your 'protocols'.

Comment: This is simply copied websites (We have copyright permission) put onto a chip that opens from an html main page that is all stored locally.  No web server involved, our larger product does, but these "chips" do not.  We are trying to use the browser preferably, but will happily use ANY pdf viewer if it will open the file.  There is no software or app that we are using other than a browser like firefox or chrome directly from the app store and same for the pdf viewer.  The only code that we access is the HTML from the pages and there is no coding in regards to opening the pdf just the link.